# Token-based access to resource without Identity & User Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, token

**My Problem:**
My app has number of pages/resources that should be accessible by **guest** users but only after providing correct pair [Resource Code - Unique Token] (each page has one Page Code and multiple unique "Tokens" issued for each user). Tokens are generated beforehand and stored in DB. After accessing the page, user will be able to interact with multiple other resources belonging to particular page.

**How I organized this so far:**
Page asks user to provide token and checks it with records in DB. If this is a correct token for resource requested, it writes cookie and then, every time user interacts with the resource or its content, controller will **every time** read cookie and check [PageCode-Token] pair with database before continuing the action.

**Question:**
Is there any other, more elegant and efficient approach? Should I use Session instead? I feel a bit bad about querying DB every time.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many users access your service, if the volume is too large it would be recommended to create a cache where all tokens are stored, thus avoiding a database overload. However if the service is not widely used this is not necessary as a database can handle a lot of requests.

You could create a cache in two ways, using ready-made software or create a small cache within the project itself.

If you choose to use software, I would recommend Redis, it is a cache database that stores values ​​with or without a timeout, ie after a while the tokens are deleted.
Keep in mind that this does not prevent you from making requests to the database, but you will always make requests to the cache first (Redis) and if the value does not exist, it is necessary to search within the database.

But if you choose to create your own, you will need to do most things manually and always knowing how much resources can be allocated. It may be more advantageous to use software than reinvent the stone.

Comment: Yoi can issue jwt token to user which will contain resources available for user. Then on server side you check available resources in that token to user and show or deny access based on information in token. You don’t need to trigger db at all in this case.